# Polyglot persistence database handling

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, mongodb

first of all, Im new in developing android.
For creating my next android app (native eLearning client for learning different scripting languages), I've got some questions about the best practise in case of databases. My goal is it, to create an android client which depends on this stack: nodejs+express+MySQL for the user handling (User handling shouldn't be schemaless) and MongoDB for the data management (Which should be schemaless, because it could vary in some future) and for example Cassandra for User activity Logs.

1. A User could be in many (private) groups, and a group can have many user (n:m), should i realise it over MySQL or should I only depends User into MySQL and Groups into NoSQL? The User will make a huge number of posts, so the posts should be saved in a NoSQL beacuse the performance (read,write). I would prefer first, best practise???
2. I read for the User login handling many about "shared prefences with encryption" and "redisDB for user session".It should have the option for a permanent login. Which one is the common or best practise way(performance, handling...) to realise for an android client?

Im glad for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

initially if you dont have heavy user base then go with mysql. as it's very simple as well as mature database flavor. You should have to use mongo nad redis only when you have performance bottle neck rather than initial database. I am suggesting this as to use the NOSQL use should have better understanding. So, go for the MySQL and use NOSQL only when it requires.